# CodeIgniter - How to set array flashdata and call the message?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter web apps using `foreach` for `user` insert data then if the submitted data is successfully inserted, I created a flashdata message called `sc_msg[]`. But I have no idea how to call it on flashdata.

```
$user = $this->input->post('user', TRUE);
foreach ($user as $u)
{
   $this->model->insert($u);
   $sc_msg[] = '- User '.$u.'has been successfully registered<br>';
}
```

This is a code how I called it on my view.

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('warning'))
        echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
```

I wanted the message called like this :

> - User `abc` has been successfully registered
> - User `bca` has been successfully registered
> - User `qwe` has been successfully registered
> - User `ewq` has been successfully registered

All `sc_msg[]` stored on `message` so I don't need to using `FOR` or `FOREACH` in the views to called it.

The problems is on my controller, I'm trying to set the message :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $sc_msg);
```

It's just print array, so I try to change `$sc_msg` into `$sc_msg[]` the result is error : Cannot use `[]` for reading.

I'm also trying to use `foreach` inside `set_flashdata` too and is failed. Unexpected foreach.

Then I'm trying to set the flashdata like this :

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $sc_msg[0].$sc_msg[1]);
```

That is printed the result but only index `0` and index `1`. Result :

> - User `abc` has been successfully registered
> - User `bca` has been successfully registered

There is another 2 messages not called for user `qwe` and `ewq`.

I have no idea how to call the message inside the `flashdata`. But, please don't give me **`for loop`** solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seen an easy way to do that Zinc.

Your message on `sc_msg[]` is already using `<br>` for next line. Okay, so what you need to do is not using foreach inside the flashdata. But using foreach to append the string from the message.

```
foreach ($sc_msg as $sm)
{
    $msg = $msg.$sm; // OR using $msg .= $sm;
}

$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $msg);
```

You can try it, If you have another way to append the string it's good. I just give an simple example for you.

Comment: You was helping me again, Cindy ! Thank you very much !